# Is there any unified way to set both `innerHTML` and `onclick` to one element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create element using its JSON description.
JavaScript now provides this:

```
elem.innerHTML = "Text"; // works fine
elem.onclick = "alert(true)"; // doesn't work

elem.setAttribute("innerHTML", "Text"); // doesn't work
elem.setAttribute("onclick", "alert(true)"); // works fine
```

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to print

```
elem.onclick = function() {alert(true)};
```

Is there any unified way to set both `innerHTML` and `onclick` to one element?
Like this:

```
var props = {"innerHTML":"Text", "onclick":"alert(true)"};
var elem = document.createElement("BUTTON");

for (property in props) elem[property] = props[property];
/* or */
for (property in props) elem.setAttribute(property, props[property]); 
/* or maybe something else */
```

Comment: Try `elem.innerHTML = "Text";`

Comment: @DavidLi: This will not work with `onclick` though.

Comment: You can use `elem.addEventListener("click", function(){alert('true')});` to add a custom click listener.

Comment: @DavidLi: Thank you for helping. Please, read the question carefully; this will not work with `innerHTML`.

Comment: I see. Can you try setting it to the innerText property instead? innerHTML may be overwriting the event handlers. This is if you only need to set the text for the element dynamically.

Comment: @DavidLi: No, it does not overwrite anything (it converts `innerHTML` to `innerhtml` and adds it to elem as an attribute of HTML node). `innerText` of course gives similar results.

Comment: Looks like my question has not yet been understood properly.

Comment: well first of all i must point out the `onclick` is not a property its an event. another if you really want to add properties  and simultaneously use event handlers then use special tokens what  mean is that if the there property of the prop object which is an event handler(like 'onclick') then they all should start with 'on' if it is a property like `.innerHTML` then they should start with `.`(dot) and if they are some thing else like functions `,setAttribute` then they should start with a `,` (comma) and thats how you establish a communication with your function and the user.

Comment: @Annisaini: well, I made `for (property in props) if (property == "onclick")`, so that each property should pass this `if` statement. That works, but I thought that could be better.

Comment: all events starts with `on` as pointed out by +alvarodms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cold use the `Function` constructor:

```
elem.onclick = new Function('', 'return alert(true);');
```

[See working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o19u6j91/)

**EDIT:** I couldn't found a unified way to do this to both events and attributes on an element, but since all events starts with `on` keyword, you could check if it's an event or attribute on your `for` loop:

```
for (property in props) {
    if(property.substr(0,2) === 'on') {
        //an event
        elem.setAttribute(property, props[property]); 
    }
    else {
        //an attribute
        elem[property] = props[property];
    }
}
```

[See working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1y0c0e75/)

Comment: it won't work with the functions like `setAttribute`, however nice try

Comment: Thanks. I've got the point.BTW, there is a specialized (experimental) method [String().startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).